# Qual o efeito da função bind() em um código cliente?

Tags: c, socket

Estava perambulando pelo Google Imagens atrás de um diagrama de estado para modelo de servidor e cliente e acabei encontrando isso aqui:

[image: Diagrama]

Despertei curiosidade em relação a imagem acima devido ao fato de ser citado o uso da função `bind()` no lado do cliente. Isso me pareceu meio estranho, pois aprendi que a função `bind()` deve ser apenas usada pelo servidor e não pelo cliente.

Contudo, venho aqui com as seguintes dúvidas:

- Que papel a função `bind()` desempenha em um código cliente?
- Por que no diagrama diz que o uso da função `bind()` é opcional?
- Como a função `bind()` poderia ser aplicada no código abaixo?

  client.c

  ```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>
  #include <string.h>

  #include <netdb.h>
  #include <unistd.h>
  #include <arpa/inet.h>
  #include <sys/types.h>
  #include <sys/socket.h>
  #include <netinet/in.h>

  #define SRV_ADDR "127.0.0.1"
  #define SRV_PORT "9009"

  int make_socket(void){

      int ecode, sockfd;

      struct addrinfo *results=NULL, hints;

      memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(struct addrinfo));

      hints.ai_family=AF_INET;
      hints.ai_socktype=SOCK_STREAM;
      hints.ai_protocol=IPPROTO_TCP;

      if((ecode=getaddrinfo(SRV_ADDR, SRV_PORT, &hints, &results))!=0){

          sockfd=-1;

      }else{

          struct addrinfo *it=NULL;

          for(it=results; it!=NULL; it=it->ai_next){

              if((sockfd=socket(it->ai_family, it->ai_socktype, it->ai_protocol))==-1){

                  continue;
              }

              if(connect(sockfd, it->ai_addr, it->ai_addrlen)==0){

                  break;
              }

              close(sockfd);
          }

          freeaddrinfo(results);

          if(it==NULL){

              sockfd=-1;
          }
      }

      return sockfd;
  }

  short get_msg(char *msg, size_t n){

      int rv;

      if(fgets(msg, n, stdin)!=NULL){

          size_t len=strlen(msg);

          msg[len-1]='\0'; //elimina o \n

          rv=0;

      }else{

          rv=-1;
      }

      return rv;
  }

  int main(void){

      int sockfd=make_socket();

      if(sockfd!=-1){

          short rv;
          char msg[101];

          printf("\n");

          do{

              do{

                  printf("Você >");

                  if((rv=get_msg(msg, 101))!=0){

                      printf("\n* Falha na leitura!");
                      printf("\n  |.__Escreva a mensagem novamente.\n\n");
                  }

                  send(sockfd, msg, 101, 0);

              }while(rv!=0);

              if(strcmp(msg, "!exit")!=0){

                  recv(sockfd, msg, 101, 0);

                  printf("Estranho: %s\n", msg);
              }

          }while(strcmp(msg, "!exit")!=0);

          close(sockfd);
      }

      return 0;
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se não for feito 'bind' no socket utilizado no 'connect' então é feito um bind automático em uma porta disponível, geralmente uma porta chamada de "efêmera". (Isso também acontece quando se faz um 'bind' na porta 0).

Em geral não é feito o 'bind' na porta local em uma conexão client (criada por 'connect') porque não há necessidade, mas eventualmente pode haver casos de uso que isso pode ser feito. Você poderia criar uma aplicação server que só aceitasse conexões vinda de um client que utilize uma porta local específica, por exemplo.